# Why does my git bash shell show up as a separate tile in my task bar, when running as admin?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, git-bash, pinning

**EDIT:**

**Other SE users cannot reproduce this so it's likely an issue with my company's GPO. Holding open until I can send my helpdesk a link to this write-up.**

---

I use Git for Windows, on Windows 10. Specifically I use `git bash`, `git gui` and `gitk` together as my Git interface.

When I boot up my machine I have 2 git tiles pinned to my Task Bar - the icon for the bash, and the icon for `wish.exe` (`git gui` and `gitk`).

[image]

If click on the bash icon and run-as-admin, and I get the admin auth pop-up, because corporate policy has decided that we're allowed full admin access, but that has to be as a 2nd user, which we don't log in as:

[image]

I enter my admin creds, and get my admin prompt. But it's opened as a separate tile on the Task Bar :(

[image]

What's worse is that I can't "Pin" that tile, which causes all sorts of annoyance, because it's no longer with the other git tiles :(

**Why is it opening as a separate tile? And can I stop it from doing that (i.e. make it use the same tile whether admin or not)**

---

*Comparison to other programs / attempts:*

- *It doesn't do this when I open as non-admin.*
- *No other program does the same thing when I open **them** as admin.*
- *I can pin other programs that are either std-user-by-default or admin-by-default, and they behave just fine.*
- *Same behviour occurs for git whether set up as "exe is std-user-by-default and I right-click to run-as-admin" or as "exe is admin-by-default and I left-/middle-click to open".

Comment: Why don’t you just modify the shortcut to always launch as an Administrator.  Multiple elevated instances of the Git prompt should absolutely be grouped together and separately from non-elevated Git prompts.

Comment: Also of note - when I open 2 elevated Git prompts, they still don't group together.

Comment: Which is interesting, because opening 2 non-elevanted Git prompts ***do*** group!?

Comment: I elevated Git Bash as an Administrator and was unable to reproduce this behavior.  I suspect the behavior is due to your corporate group policy.

Comment: booo :( Thanks for the help. Does that render the question off-topic?

Comment: @Brondahl unfortunately yes, off topic.

Comment: @DavidPostill cool. If I click the delete button, will the post still be visible, if you know the URL? I've nicely written up my problem - it would be useful if I could just send my helpdesk team a link to this page.

Comment: @Brondahl No. But you could leave it open until your support team has seen it ...

Comment: Cool, that works.